# How to create Html table in table from server side visual basic

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vb.net, html-table

I'm working in asp.net, visual basic.
I need to create html table inside a table.
I need to create all through server side.

The table will be with 6 cols and n rows. in the last col (more data) will be a link, and when clicking on that link (let say on row2) it will expand the specific row and show another table with 5 cols and m rows
clicking on that link again will close the row and hide the inside table.

For now I just try to do it in the client side, a little example to me, but I'm stuck.

I have this for now:

```
    <div id="shutfuyotTable">
    <table class="tblShutaf" dir="rtl" runat="server">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>num</td>
                <td>name</td>
                <td>sum1</td>
                <td>sum2</td>
                <td>notes</td>
                <td>moreData</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td>row1</td>
                <td><a href='#' id="row1">row1</a></td>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <table id="Table1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td>row2</td>
                <td><a href='#' id="row2">row2</a></td>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <table id="Table2">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>row3</td>
                <td>row3</td>
                <td>row3</td>
                <td>row3</td>
                <td>row3</td>
                <td><a href='#' id="row3">row3</a></td>
                <tr>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <table id="Table3">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>2</td>
                                    <td>3</td>
                                    <td>4</td>
                                    <td>5</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the css I put row1 (id) as display: none;

I'm not manage to do the javascript, that when I'm clicking on the link it will show or hide the table.

What do I need to add in this code (Maybe onClick function?!?)
and what I need to do in javascript?

Comment: Your html is broken, you have tr inside tr, which is wrong. And yes you need some sort of click-event on the a-tag to achieve the "show hidden content" -feature.

Comment: Thank you,
Can you please help me to correct this?
I don't know how to put a table in table as I describe.

Comment: See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jy78G/ it uses jQuery so I won't post this as an answer.